# Window message priority authoritative description

Tags: winapi, windows-ce

I have found [some](http://www.laser.ru/evgen/articles/ARTofOS2/aos2p_11.html) [places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216161/determine-priority-of-a-window-message) that mention window messages are returned by GetMessage in order of priority derived from the way they were sent with `SendMessage` being highest, than `PostMessage` and only than user input. However I couldn't find any **authoritative reference**, i.e. from Microsoft, on this. The [obvious page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927(v=vs.85)) seems to explicitly deny it (says messages are processed in FIFO order with few exceptions) and I couldn't find any other reference.

However I have an application behaviour of which suggests there are priorities (several WM_USER *thread* messages processed each second, yet clicks sometimes take many seconds to get processed). So I would like to know from an authoritative source how it is expected to behave so I can fix the application.

Note: The messages are sent with `PostThreadMessage`. I am watching messages comming out of `GetMessage`, so the non-queued messages don't come into play here. A difference between thread  and window messages possibly can.

Note: The application runs on WinCE, 5.0 in particular if it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hans's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7216350/366904) is not saying anything different than [the linked MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927#queued_messages).

Messages are processed in first-in, first-out order just like a standard queue, with a couple of special exceptions like `WM_TIMER` and `WM_PAINT` messages. Hans refers to this class of messages as those "synthesized from the window state"; MSDN just calls them out explicitly:

> With the exception of the [`WM_PAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145213) message, the [`WM_TIMER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644902) message, and the [`WM_QUIT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632641) message, the system always posts messages at the end of a message queue. This ensures that a window receives its input messages in the proper first in, first out (FIFO) sequence. The `WM_PAINT` message, the `WM_TIMER` message, and the `WM_QUIT` message, however, are kept in the queue and are forwarded to the window procedure only when the queue contains no other messages. In addition, multiple `WM_PAINT` messages for the same window are combined into a single `WM_PAINT` message, consolidating all invalid parts of the client area into a single area. Combining `WM_PAINT` messages reduces the number of times a window must redraw the contents of its client area.

The catch is that messages sent with `SentMessage` are not queued, while those posted with `PostMessage` *are*. The same article on MSDN says as much in the [next section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927#nonqueued_messages):

> Nonqueued messages are sent immediately to the destination window procedure, bypassing the system message queue and thread message queue.
>
> [...]
>
> Some functions that send nonqueued messages are `BroadcastSystemMessage`, `BroadcastSystemMessageEx`, **`SendMessage`**, `SendMessageTimeout`, and `SendNotifyMessage`.

There are no "priorities". However, the behavior you describe is easily explained. Most likely, the `WM_USER` messages are sent by calls to the `SendMessage` function, which bypasses the message queue and sends the message directly to the window procedure for the destination window. That makes them appear to be processed with a higher "priority" because they're processed immediately, before the `SendMessage` function returns, effectively bypassing the rest of the queue.

That, in turn, explains why click events take longer to be processed—because they're just shoved into the queue along with all of the other input messages, so the window doesn't get around to processing them until after it handles the messages sent directly to it with calls to `SendMessage`.

<sub>**Important caveat:** I know nothing about Windows CE, which your question indicates you're talking about specifically. The behavior I describe here is accurate for desktop versions of Windows, but if there are any differences between that behavior and that of Windows CE, I wouldn't know and I might have gotten something wrong.</sub>

Comment: That answer says differently from the MSDN document. The answer says that posted messages are still processed before the user interaction ones, which matches observation, but I don't see anything like that in the MSDN document. Also I am watching messages coming out of GetMessage, so I shouldn't even see non-queued messages.

Comment: I clarified in the answer: The user messages are sent with `PostThreadMessage` and handled by the code that calls `GetMessage`. I am looking at before dispatching to the window procedure.

Comment: @Jan: I don't know how else I can explain it to make it any more clear. There is absolutely no dissonance between Hans's answer to the linked question and the MSDN documentation. Posted messages *are* processed before special messages like `WM_PAINT` and `WM_TIMER`. Those are called out explicitly in both the answer and in the docs. Moreover, `GetMessage` *does* return/process sent messages, so you'll still see messages sent by calls to `SendMessage`. Messages sent using a `SendXxx` function will be processed first, then messages sent using a `PostXxx` function.

Comment: It's not a special "priority" thing, it's merely because of the different way that they're implemented. Sent messages aren't queued, they're processed immediately by the window procedure. Posted messages are queued and handled FIFO order, after the sent messages are disposed of. Special messages like `WM_PAINT` and `WM_TIMER` represent Boolean values and are special-cased. Also see [the documentation for the `GetMessage` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx), which gives you a brief run-down of how messages are processed if no override is provided.

Comment: No, no "special" messages are involved. Only posted thread messages and mouse events. However this link *does* mention posted messages are processed before the hardware one. Please, put this link into the main answer (and remove most of the rest of it, the link is the only relevant bit I was looking for). Thanks.

Comment: Hm, I was looking at the WinCE version of the documentation and it does not contain the relevant remark. Only the desktop version does, but it appears it applies to the CE version as well.