# MFC - Add function call to mainloop?

Tags: windows, user-interface, mfc

I am fixing a MFC applivation written in C++. It is a GUI and it communicates with an external module connected to the PC via USB.

I want to avoid using a separate thread. Is there a way I can add things to the mainloop so that it runs continously rather than being event based?

I want the mainloop to make a call to a function runCommStack() in every loop.

Comment: Please reply here instead stackoverflow.com/questions/18234709/mfc-gui-application-rewrite-threading-messaging-document-view-etc-advice-n

Answer (score 1):

Some possible approaches:

1. You can use `CWnd::SetTimer` to set a timer.
2. You can override `CWinApp::OnIdle` (called by `CWinApp::Run`).
3. You can override `CWinApp:Run`, copying and modifying the original MFC's `CWinApp:Run`. This definitely is not the easiest solution.
4. You can create a background thread.

It depends on the requirements of `runCommStack()`. Is this function running long times? Then you probably won't want to run it in the GUI thread. Does runCommStack need to get called every n milliseconds? Then it might also be better to run it in it's own thread. In other cases you can just use the timer or OnIdle approach.

Regarding solution 1: as Tim pointed out `WM_TIMER` messages are low priority messages and will not be passed to the application while other higher-priority messages are in the message queue. See also [Determine priority of a window message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216161/determine-priority-of-a-window-message).

With solution 2 you should remind that `OnIdle` will only be called if no window message is available. So this is quite the same as solution 1 (in fact a little worse).

Also keep in mind that solutions 2 and 3 might result in your `runCommStack` not getting called if a dialog's `DoModal()` is called or if a message box is displayed. This is because during `MessageBox()` the control is not returned to `CWinApp::Run()`.

I'ld implement solution 1 or 4.

Comment: In contrasting approaches 1 and 2 you seem to imply that `WM_TIMER` messages are generated when other messages are in the message queue. This is not the case; `WM_TIMER` messages are generated only if the message queue is empty, no mouse input has to be handled an no painting is to be done.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for pointing that out, I was not aware of it. I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When there are no messages (like keys, mouse, repaint) arriving the main loop suspends the program, waiting for the next message. So the idea of adding a call to the main loop will give you very erratic operation. For example, minimizing your window will stop all the USB communication.

Using SetTimer and calling your runCommStack function in a WM_TIMER handler will probably be much more satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use idle processing with [CWinApp::OnIdle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-ch/library/3e077sxt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx); this will work if reading your USB device takes only a short amount of time, otherwise the user interface will be blocked during long reads.

But using a separate thread is definitely a better method.