# WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext execution order of posted callbacks

Tags: c#, winforms, synchronization

I uses `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` to dispatch execution of callbacks in main UI thread (application is WinForms). The dispatching callbacks code runs in worker thread and it should not be synced with callback so I use [`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Post()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext.post?view=netframework-4.6.2#System_Windows_Forms_WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext_Post_System_Threading_SendOrPostCallback_System_Object_) method. But callbacks must be executed in main UI thread in order of posting them in `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`.

Does anybody know whether `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` executes posted callbacks in posting order or not?
I haven't found this information in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.6.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, order is preserved.

[`WindowsFormSynchronizationContext.Post`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Windows.Forms/System/Windows/Forms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs,de633159d3cb47c3,references) calls [`Control.BeginInvoke`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Windows.Forms/System/Windows/Forms/Control.cs,92512f20d564f18e) which calls [`MarshaledInvoke`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Windows.Forms/System/Windows/Forms/Control.cs,dc49fb4c2140594f) which calls [`PostMessage`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Windows.Forms/System/Windows/Forms/Control.cs,6912).

[The order among messages which are posted to a window is preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7216350/1086121) (but messages which are sent have priority over ones which are posted).